# Most efficient method for computing Singular Value Decomposition for an upper triangular matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra, svd, matrix-decomposition

There are several methods available for computing SVD of a general matrix. I am interested to know about the best approach which could be used for computing SVD of an upper triangular matrix. Please suggest me an algorithm which could be optimized for this special case of matrices.

Comment: That sounds like a math question. Perhaps [math.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sure I will put this question on that forum as well.